# How do I connect to MSSQL server from Linux

Tags: sql-server, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I need a read-only access to a MSSQL server from a Linux box (more precisely, from a Heroku Cedar stack via Rails). Is it doable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need ActiveRecord Database Adapter for SQL Server, you can find an installation guide [here](http://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/ruby/rails.html).